# Visual Studio 2013 "Failed to calculate connection key" when pressing New Query in Server Explorer

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

Trying to view a table in a SQL db, by right clicking the table and pressing New Query, throws an error "Failed to calculate connection key".
What does this mean and how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I used to resolve this error was by closing VS & deleting the SEVIEW file located at:

```
C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ServerExplorer
```

The downside to this was I had to re-enter all of the server connection details after the delete; however, I was able to directly execute the Stored Procedures and queries directly in VS.  It looks like the stored server keys are located in this directory, based on this SO post